# why isn't the position updating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I have a game where there is the player and the enemy. The enemy should follow the player when he sees him (is in range).But only the enemies that spawns near him (in range) follows him,the rest just ignores the player even if the player is in the range.This is because the position is not updating.how can I update it?
The code:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{

    if (Vector2.Distance(player.position, transform.position) <= 40f)
    {
        Vector2 dir = player.position - transform.position;
        transform.Translate(dir.normalized * enemyspeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, Space.World);
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) <= 0.4f)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);

        }
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: "only the enemies that are in apropriate range are following the player and the rest just ingores him" Isn't that what you want? Only the enemies who sees the player (i.e. in the range) should follow the player, right?

Comment: The problem is that the enemies that spawns near the player (in range) follows him ,the rest of the enemies ignores him ,but i need all the enemies to follow the player (when he is in the range).

Comment: just move the `Vector2 dir=` and `transform.Translate` lines outside the if clause

Comment: Do you mean that the rest of the enemies doesn't follow the player even if they come close? If so, please write it more clearly by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: no, all the enemies on the map should follow the player. That's the idea

Comment: but by doing: `if (Vector2.Distance(player.position, transform.position) <= 40f)` you only move the enemies that are close to the player

Comment: if i move the Vector2 dir= and transform.Translate lines outside the if clause they will follow the spawnpoint of the character

Comment: If they follow the spawn point, then `player.position` is most likely not updated.

Comment: @NicoSchertler exactly. make sure you log the player.position and see if that is updated correctly

Comment: yeah,this is the problem,but how can I update it?

Comment: you really shouldn't update the question code or text like that. If you have an update, add it like an update but don't keep rewriting the text because the initial question will no longer make any sense when reading answers or other comments.

Comment: This is [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

By executing these 2 lines in the if clause, you only apply it to the enemies close to the player:

```
Vector2 dir = player.position - transform.position;
transform.Translate(dir.normalized * enemyspeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, Space.World);
```

So, just move them outside and you are good to go

```
void FixedUpdate()
{

    Vector2 dir = player.position - transform.position;
    transform.Translate(dir.normalized * enemyspeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, Space.World);
    if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position) <= 0.4f)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}
```

**Update:**

Regarding the player position, you may want to have a look at this:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/451000/blocks-wont-render-in-realtime.html

Comment: thanks ,but I still cant update the player position

Comment: @CristianBolohan check the link I attached

Comment: Thanks it helped me ,still got a error ,but i will fix it myself.